# Limiting the Width and Height of the Global Costmap in NAV2

Tags: navigation

I'm currently working on a robot project using the NAV2 package of the ROS Navigation Stack. Since my map is large and the computational resources on my system are limited, I want to limit the global costmap area to 20 meters.

Is there a way to limit the global cost map to a specific area, such as a 20x20 meter region, rather than creating it for the entire map? I would greatly appreciate any feedback, suggestions or solutions you can provide.

I tried to add width and height to the global cost map properties but it didn't work.

always_send_full_costmap: false
This option also did not reduce computer resource usage

Thank you from now!

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the map?

Try doing the following:

- Increase the resolution value of the global costmap.
- Decrease the update_frequency and publish_frequency values under global costmap.

Comment: I work in a very precise area I need high resolution so I cant increase the resolution
My global costmap frequency already set very low
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0